# iOS Maps, any way to manually specify a location?

Tags: ios, geolocation

My cottage is along a road that Maps is clueless about - the name is spelled wrong, it’s missing a North, it’s shows all sorts of connecting roads that don’t exist, etc.

The most annoying problem, however, is that all the street numbers are wrong. Put in my address and you end up about two miles away.

Is there a way I can manually indicate the precise location of my address? I can drop a pin, but can I say that’s the address so that when I send the contact to people they also get the right location?

Comment: Use Google maps. I hate to sound so pessimistic, but that's your solution. Apple Maps' dropped pins are a poor afterthought. You save a precise location, even add it to Contacts so it will be there next time… it recalls a 'postcode'. Ne'er the twain shall meet. It's absolutely fine so long as it remains a 'dropped pin' you just can't export it anyewhere, not even to Contacts.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/351110/85275 & perhaps https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/178482/85275